# ASP.NET Core 6 : cannot resolve symbol 'Ok'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I have some issues with ASP.NET Core 6.

I have a method in a controller:

```
[ HttpPost( "create" ) ]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAccountAsync()
{
    return Ok( new ApiResponse<object>
    {
        IsSuccess = true
    });
}
```

[image]

I was doing it in .NET Framework and it works fine.

This is also full controller code:

```
using System.Net.Mime;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MobileTrackerWebApi.ApiHandlers;
using MobileTrackerWebApi.Database;
using MobileTrackerWebApi.System;

namespace MobileTrackerWebApi.Controllers;

[Controller]
[Route("account")]
public class AccountController
{
    private static ApiDbContext _dbContext;
    private static EnvReader    _reader;
    
    public AccountController( EnvReader envReader, ApiDbContext  dbContext)
    {
        Guard.NotNull(envReader);
        Guard.NotNull(dbContext, ErrorCode.DbContextIsNull);

        _reader = envReader;
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [ HttpPost( "create" ) ]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAccountAsync()
    {
        return Ok( new ApiResponse<object>
        {
            IsSuccess = true
        });
    }
}
```

I also notified that OkObjectResult not working too.

.csproj config

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: please show your full controller.

Comment: I would suggest trying `return new OkObjectResult(your response));`

Comment: @DanielA.White it it a empty controller, but okey, i edited my question.

Comment: @IgorTopolski it is even worse "Method, delegate, or event is expected."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your controller must inherit from ControllerBase. Ok is a method of ControllerBase :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Oh, i added an attribute but i forgot about inherit, thanks man!